# jquery timepicker throws:Uncaught TypeError even after including the necessary files

Tags: jquery, timepicker

I am trying to call the timepicker function, but it constantly throws:

Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).timepicker is not a function(…)

I see the file loaded in the network, but cant access the timepicker function.I also have jquery and jquery-ui loaded before this file gets loaded.
Here is how im including the script:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.8.9/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
```

js:

```
    $("#timestart").timepicker();
```

html:

```
<label>Start Date</label>
<input type="text" id="timestart"/>
```

I have been struggling to find out where im going wrong. any clue why does the timepicker function is not accessible and throws error?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the jquery.timepicker.js loaded **before** you run the JS?

Comment: yes... i debugged to see its getting loaded before the timepicker call

Comment: Can you create a fiddle that reproduces the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you include the [jquery.timepicker.css](https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker/blob/master/jquery.timepicker.css) file as well?

I used your same code in this [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xrb7cf6s/).

```
<label>Start Date</label>
<input type="text" id="timestart"/>
```

and

```
 $("#timestart").timepicker();
```